# How can I make the window invisible when winrar is started with the Process class

Tags: c#, runtime, winrar

I want the winrar Process window to be invisible.

This code line doesn't seem to have any effect:

```
        //the_StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

How can I achieve that the window stays hidden?

This is the code I use to start winrar:

```
     public void compress(string inputfilename, string outputfilename, string workingfolder)
    {
        string the_rar;
        RegistryKey the_Reg;
        object the_Obj;
        string the_Info;
        ProcessStartInfo the_StartInfo;
        Process the_Process;
        try
        {
            the_Reg = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"WinRAR\shell\open\command");//for winrar path
            the_Obj = the_Reg.GetValue("");
            the_rar = the_Obj.ToString();
            the_Reg.Close();
            the_rar = the_rar.Substring(1, the_rar.Length - 7);
            the_Info = " a " + " " + outputfilename + " " + " " + inputfilename;//i dare say for parameter
            the_StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

            the_StartInfo.FileName = the_rar;
            the_StartInfo.Arguments = the_Info;
            the_StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            the_StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingfolder;
            the_Process = new Process();
            the_Process.StartInfo = the_StartInfo;
            the_Process.Start();//starting compress Process
            the_Process.Close();
            the_Process.Dispose();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use a native library rather than shelling?

Comment: @Kaboo `WinRar` comes with a command line utility (`Rar.exe` and `Unrar.exe`) to compress/ extract archive. You might wanna try using that instead of using the GUI (`WinRar.exe`).

Answer (score 2):

when you use ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden you must also set ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute to false.

## Reason :

If the UseShellExecute property is true or the UserName and Password properties are not null, the CreateNoWindow property value is ignored and a new window is created.

```
public void compress(string inputfilename, string outputfilename, string workingfolder)
{
    string the_rar;
    RegistryKey the_Reg;
    object the_Obj;
    string the_Info;
    ProcessStartInfo the_StartInfo;
    Process the_Process;
    try
    {
        the_Reg = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"WinRAR\shell\open\command");//for winrar path
        the_Obj = the_Reg.GetValue("");
        the_rar = the_Obj.ToString();
        the_Reg.Close();
        the_rar = the_rar.Substring(1, the_rar.Length - 7);
        the_Info = " a " + " " + outputfilename + " " + " " + inputfilename;//i dare say for parameter
        the_StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

        the_StartInfo.FileName = the_rar;
        the_StartInfo.Arguments = the_Info;
        the_StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        the_StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        the_StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingfolder;
        the_Process = new Process();
        the_Process.StartInfo = the_StartInfo;
        the_Process.Start();//starting compress Process
        the_Process.Close();
        the_Process.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```